# Drawable and layout folder of 1024x600 resoltion

Tags: java, android, screen-resolution

I have i-ball tablet of 1024x600 resolution(hdpi).then please give me name of drawable and layout folder.i have other devices like 1024x600 resolution.but this device consider as a mdpi density.i already search it.but no one device has cosider 1024x600 resolution with hdpi.
    All 1024x600 device has mdpi resolution.so please give me some solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you solve this after putting images??

Comment: yes i have solved  this issue .i am using folder name         drawable-sw400dp-hdpi and layout-sw400dp-hdpi.

Answer (score 0):

You can specifically have a layout folder for particular resolution. Like in your case you can name a layout folder for that specific resolution like this:

layout-normal-land-1024x600

Comment: its not working.because of my device is hdpi resolution of 1024x600 .

Answer (score 0):

Try `values-sw1024dp` but I don't think 1024 is the proper value(it is only if pixel density is around 160), so you have to determine that either by calculating dp from pixel size, or experimentally